# About the one point compactification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactification

I have a question about the one-point compactification, given an arbitrary topological space $(X,\tau)$, does the one-point compactification always exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No. A compactification of a space $X$ is an embedding of $X$ as a dense subset of a compact Hausdorff space, so if $X$ isn’t already Hausdorff, it has no compactification. And if $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, it will be closed in any Hausdorff space, so the only compact Hausdorff space in which it is dense is itself. It turns out that $X$ has a one-point compactification if and only if it is a locally compact, non-compact Hausdorff space.

However, one can start with any non-compact space $X$ and form the [Alexandroff extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) $Y$ by adding a single point in such a way as to get a compact space in which the original space is a dense subspace. (Specifically, the open nbhds of the added point are the complements in $Y$ of closed, compact subsets of $X$.) It is an actual compactification, however, if and only if you start with a locally compact, non-compact Hausdorff space, in which case it’s the one-point compactification of that space. (Note that some people do call it the one-point compactification, not requiring compactifications to be Hausdorff.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes (*provided that the word "compactification" does not involve Hausdorffness, see @Brian M. Scott's answer. For me, a [compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)#Definition) of $X$ is just a compact space containing $X$ as a dense subspace. Under this definition, the one-point compactification of $X$ is a compactification if, and only if, $X$ is not already compact*). As a set, it is $X \cup \{\infty\}$ and its open sets are the open sets in $X$ and the complements of closed compact subsets of $X$, where you add $\infty$ to each one of them. In some applications you want the compactification to be Hausdorff, in which case you need to add more assumptions, namely that $X$ itself is Hausdorff and locally compact.

Comment: why can't you just add one open set which is $X\bigcup\left\{ \inf\right\} $?

Comment: Because this is only compact in pathological cases.

Comment: why? any open Cover will need to contain the set $X\bigcup\left\{ \inf\right\} $  (in order to contain inf) and then you can take this set as a finite cover

Comment: You're totally right. I guess this is the reason why people require Hausdorffness, then?

Comment: I think so. I'm not sure this new topology gets any  of the properties of the original one, so maybe that is why people are not interested in it

Comment: This seems like a reasonable explanation. I still stand by my answer, however, since "one-point compactification" and "Alexandroff extension" are synonyms (at least on Wikipedia), and the above construction always yields a compactification (provided the original space is not closed in its compactification, i.e., if $X$ is not cmpact).

Comment: The reason is that if you define the compactification by adding just $X\cup \infty$ then you change all closed sets of the original topology.

Comment: The reason for it being uninteresting or for it not being a compactification?

Comment: You are right. The reason to not be interesting. The new space does not retain important information of the original space, i.e., the closed compact sets.